# Checking If Two Separate Rows have Duplicates in Multiple Columns Then Performing an Operation (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database of real estate property addresses with columns containing different in formation about the building such as square footage and property type, as well as owner name and phone number. Some of the entries are complete duplicates, meaning that two different rows have the exact same data in all cells.

Some of the entries have all of the same entries except that the building square footage for the two entries are different. In this case I want to use VBA to check for a duplicate address, then if the is a match I want to check again to see if their corresponding square footages are the same.

If the addresses and square footages are both the same then i want to delete one of the entries completely. If the addresses are the same and the square footages are different, I want to add the two square footages of the entries together and delete one of them.

Here is the code that I have been working on. I am not sure where to go from here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Range1 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("A1:J4")
For i = 1 To i = 4
For j = 1 To j = 4
If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 5) <> Cells(j, 5) Then
Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value + Cells(j, 5).Value
Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete

End If

If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 5) = Cells(j, 5) Then
Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run this? what error do you get?

A few quick things, best practice sort of stuff. 

For i = 1 To i = 4 should just be For i = 1 To 4. 
You should have next i and next j somewhere to show the end of the loop. 
If you delete row j you should also say j = j - 1 otherwise you will miss a row in your loop.

See how you go with this I'll help more when I get home if you need

Comment: when deleting rows it's also often useful to loop backwards (bottom to top) so the remaining rows don't shift when you delete a row. Use `For i = 4 To 1 Step -1` for that. You also need to make sure you don't compare the row to itself or you will delete every row. You can do that by having your second loop go from 1 to i-1. Finally, you could try to replace the inner loop with a `.Find` operation which will be considerably faster.

Comment: You're missing both next statements. Even if you added them this code would fail.  You need to iterate from last to first when deleting.  If you don't the counters will miss rows.  For that reason it is very difficult to delete rows with two nested loops.  You may be able to compensate by decrementing the counters when the rows are deleted but it'll be very tedious to get it right.

Comment: After further review; if you could get this to work it would simply delete all 4 rows.  You comparing the same cells with both counters `Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3)` so at some point they will both be referring to the same cell and if these are not equal `Cells(i, 5) <> Cells(j, 5)` delete the row but if the same cells are equal `Cells(i, 5) = Cells(j, 5)` delete the row.

Comment: You will greatly benefit from watching this complete series on Youtube: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  [Excel VBA Introduction Part 16 - For Next Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyWrLH7monI&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=18) is the relevant one but you really should watch them all.